# Compare 2 SQL server database from inside a vb.net program

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, smo

I'm using VB.net 2013 , SQL server 2008R2 , and SMO.

I have 2 sql server databases ( actually as backup files .bak ).

I need to find the differences between Database1 and Database2 ( only structure and relationships ) and after to apply these changes on Database2  in order that this database will have the same structure and relationship with Database1.

How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is *not* trivial and is typically addressed using specialized tools. Not only do you have to find the differences but you need to decide how to apply them to the target database. In fact, SQL Server Database Tools already contains both Schema and Data comparisons. The only case where a tool may not be required is when you use Entity Framework migrations to apply schema changes to an application database

Comment: Actually I use Entity Framework , but I use Database First and I've read that is not possible to  do this.

Comment: As I said, it's not trivial, you need a tool. And Visual Studio already [contains a tool for schema comparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). SSDT can be used as a standalone environment or from inside Visual Studio

Comment: Ok , but I need to do this process inside of my program ,  on runtime. Can this tool help ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A tool won't help you if you are trying to do something dangerous. It also won't help you upgrade a database schema because it doesn't know how your application works. The reason it's not trivial is that you *can't* guess how to migrate eg a column deletion, the creation of a NOT NULL column, the renaming of a column etc. That's why EF has migrations and tools allow you to modify their script before they apply it

Comment: What I'm trying to do I have explained on my question. I have 2 databases.  Inside my program , on runtime , I want to find the differencies between Database1 and Database2 , and after to apply these changes to database2 in order that 2 databases will have the same structure. BUT I WANT TO DO THIS FROM INSIDE MY APPLICATION ON RUNTIME.

Comment: What @PanagiotisKanavos is trying to say is that what you are asking is a very complex question. You can't just dump the structural changes from one database onto another without understanding what those changes are doing and what they are for which is why commercial tools that do this have all sorts of capabilities for altering the migration process to suit your business case.

Comment: @Colin - I understand that , but I don't think I've asked a tool to do this quickly. I want to know that inside a vb.net program , is there any way to compare the 2 databases , find the differencies and after apply these into other database. For example SMO has any way to do this ?

Comment: @alex you can't automagically upgrade data. Only EF Migrations provides an out-of-the-box way and even that, essentially replicates what *you* have to do by hand - create a script with the schema and *data* migrations, keep a log of deployed versions and check that the database hasn't drifted from the last deployed version before upgrading. With DB first you would have to create the scripts using one of the comparison tools.

Comment: @alex to put it another way, you are asking the wrong question. If you are trying to find how to deploy new database versions, the answer isn't "by automatically applying a diff between two databases". The schema diff is just the first step, the rest you have to code yourself. And the customer may change your database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry , I'm not asking for an automatic process. I'm clear that I have to do this by code. But I just want I way how can I start and do this by code. For example How can I compare tables and fields one by one , find and temporary save a difference (when is found )....... After I finish the comparison how can I apply these changes to other database. But I don't know what should I use to code this. I've read something about SMO but I'm still unclear.

Comment: @alex SQL Server's [Data-Tier Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx) together with Database projects *may* be what you are looking for: a package that contains a database's artifacts that handles versioning and drift detection. DACPACs generated from SSDT contain the changes from each version to the next, but that requires that all schema modifications occur inside the Database project itself

Comment: Actually , there's a open source project that can do this , but the problem is how to transform in a library that can be used inside another project.https://opendbiff.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to write a program to do this?

If not the easiest way would be to restore the databases onto a SQL Server and then use Visual Studio 2012 which has SQL Scheme and SQL Data Comparisons or an alternative piece of software.

This is probably not the place for this type of question.

Comment: Have you read my question ? I need to do this inside my vb.net program.